# Defining my own max function with variable arguments

Tags: clojure, variadic-functions

I'm learning Clojure solving the problems listed on [4clojure](http://4clojure.com). One of the exercises is to create your own `max` function with variable arguments.

I'm trying to solve this easy problem using the REPL and I got to this solution:

```
(defn my-max 
    [first & more] (calc-max first more))

(defn calc-max 
    [m x] 
        (cond (empty? x) m
            (> (first x) m) (calc-max (first x) (rest x))
            :else calc-max m (rest x)))
```

Which works fine but the exercise doesn't allow the use of `def` and therefore I must crunch both functions into one. When I replace the `calc-max` reference with its code the result is:

```
(defn my-max 
    [first & more] 
    ((fn calc-max 
        [m x] 
            (cond (empty? x) m
                (> (first x) m) (calc-max (first x) (rest x))
                :else calc-max m (rest x)))
                    first more))
```

But this code doesn't work and returns the next error:

```
user=> (my-max 12 3 4 5 612 3)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

I guess this error comes from trying to evaluate the result of the `calc-max` function and I guess it's a syntax error on my part, but I can't figure out how to resolve it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I like to define my helpers for 4clojure problems as a `letfn` wrapped around the result, which ends up having identical semantics to separated `defn`s. For example, `(letfn [(calc-max [m x] ...)] (fn my-max [first & more] ...))`Now the two instances of `first` are lexically separate and won't collide, and you don't have to do any rewriting to either function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Real error is that you called parameter `first` - it rebinds real `first` function to number!** Just change name to something other, and your variant will work.  Although it maybe better explicitly name function, instead of calling anonymous function, for example, you can declare `calc-max` as local function using `letfn`, for example. So your `my-max` will look like:

```
(defn my-max [ff & more]
  (letfn [(calc-max [m x] 
            (cond (empty? x) m
                  (> (first x) m) (calc-max (first x) 
                                            (rest x))
                  :else (calc-max m (rest x))))]
    (calc-max ff more)))
```

Although, I think, that you can write simpler code:

```
(defn my-max [& more] (reduce max more))
```

Comment: wow, completely missed that first, I was doomed by the example of page 32 of the book which shows how a var arg function which now I know is wrong!

Comment: you can even write a simpler code using max as: (max 12 3 3 441 123) but the exercise won't let you used the core max function ;)

Comment: then you can replace it with 2-args function, like: `#(if (> %1 %2) %1 %2)`

Answer (score 14):

Here is the function I used to solve it.  The point is not to use max at all.

```
(fn [& args] (reduce (fn [x y] (if (> x y) x y) ) args ) )
```

Comment: Smart and short answer, brilliant!

Answer (score 4):

Your function doesn't work because `first` in `fn` treated as function and not as input value. So when you write

```
user=> (my-max 12 3 4 5 612 3)
```

it's talling that can't cast 12 to function. Simply, it can be rewrited as

```
(defn my-max1 [fst & more]
  ((fn calc-max [m x]
     (cond (empty? x) m
           (> (first x) m) (calc-max (first x) (rest x))
           :else (calc-max m (rest x))))
    fst more))
```

or even without `fn`

```
(defn my-max [x & xs]
  (cond (empty? xs) x
        (> (first xs) x) (recur (first xs) (rest xs))
        :else (recur x (rest xs))))
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a little more on the exception that you are seeing: whenever Clojure throws something like

```
java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

at you it means that it tried to call a function but the thing it tried to call was not a function but something else. This usually occurs when you have code like this

```
(smbl 1 2 3)
```

If `smbl` refers to a function, clojure will execute it with parameters 1 2 and 3. But if `smbl` doesn't refer to a function then you will see an error like the one above. This was my pointer in looking through your code and, as 4e6 pointed out, `(first x)` is the culprit here because you named your function argument `first`.

Answer (score 0):

Not as good as the reduce but ok ba:

(fn [& args] 
     (loop [l args, maxno (first args)] 
        (if (empty? l)
           maxno 
           (if (> maxno (first l) )
               (recur (rest l) maxno)
               (recur (rest l) (first l))))))

Can use cond I suppose