# How to write a max function in clojure for a '()

Tags: clojure

I very new to Clojure as of a couple of days ago.
I am trying to create a my-max function which must work as below
`(my-max '(8 18 98 55 4 5 6)) => 98`

I've looked at other similar questions such as [Defining my own max function with variable arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503030/defining-my-own-max-function-with-variable-arguments)

I've tried to write functions like the ones in the post, but I don't understand why they don't work when the it's written with the parenthesis, for example
`(my-max '(8 18 98 55 4 5 6)) (8 18 98 55 4 5 6)`
but if I remove the list and write `(my-max 8 18 98 55 4 5 6) => 98`, then it works.

I am trying to understand how can I write a max function that works for a `()` and if it's empty then it should return `nil`.

The function that I tried to work on

```
(defn my-max [x & xs]
  (cond (empty? xs) x
        (> (first xs) x) (recur (first xs) (rest xs))
        :else (recur x (rest xs))))
```

Comment: Thanks, guys! Do you guys have any recommendations on great websites that I can learn Clojure as a rookie? :)

Comment: Grab yourself a [book](https://www.braveclojure.com/clojure-for-the-brave-and-true/), acquaint yourself with [Clojure cheatsheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet)

Comment: https://clojure.org/community/resources is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(require
        '[clojure.test :refer [is]])

(letfn [(my-max
            ([] nil)
            ([x] x)
            ([a b] (if (< a b) b a))
            ([a b & rest] (reduce my-max (conj rest a b))))]
    (is (= nil (my-max)))
    (is (= 1 (my-max 1)))
    (is (= 2 (my-max 1 2)))
    (is (= 3 (my-max 1 3 2)))
    (is (= 4 (my-max 4 1 3 2))))
```

Comment: Could you explain your code so that I can understand it completely? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply built-in [`max`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/max) or function from akond's answer:

```
(defn my-max [lst]
  (when (seq lst)
    (apply max lst)))

(my-max '(8 18 98 55 4 5 6))
=> 98
(my-max '())
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use reduce:

```
(defn my-max [& args]
  (reduce #(if (< %1 %2) %2 %1) args))
```

`reduce` begins with first argument collected in `args` and compares it with the next element in `args`. If the next element - which is inserted as `%2` is bigger than the first element `%1`, then the output of the inner anonymous function is `%2` otherwise `%1`. This output becomes the `%1` in the next call of the anonymous function and the next element becomes `%2`. Thus it is as if the inner function compares always the next element with the recent maximal element and keeps the bigger of both for the next comparison. Finally the last output of the inner anonymous function will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

and one more, just for fun:

you can employ `max-key` for that:

```
(def my-max (partial apply max-key #(or % ##-Inf) nil))

user> (my-max [1 2 3])
;;=> 3

user> (my-max [])
;;=> nil

user> (my-max [1])
;;=> 1

user> (my-max [2 1])
;;=> 2
```